# SVM Prediction is dropping values

Tags: r, svm, predict

I'm running the SVM model on a dataset, which runs through fine on the train/fitted model. However when I run it for the prediction/test data, it seems to be dropping rows for some reason, when I try to add 'pred_SVM' back into the dataset, the lengths are different. 
Below is my code

```
#SVM MODEL
 SVM_swim <- svm(racetime_mins ~ event_date+ event_month +year 
 +event_id + 
              gender + place + distance+ New_Condition+
              raceNo_Updated +  
              handicap_mins +points+
              Wind_Speed_knots+ 
              Air_Temp_Celsius +Water_Temp_Celsius +Wave_Height_m,
          data = SVMTrain, kernel='linear')
summary(SVM_swim)

#Predict Race_Time Using Test Data
pred_SVM <- predict(SVM_swim, SVMTest, type ="response")
View(pred_SVM)
#Add predicted Race_Times back into the test dataset.
SVMTest$Pred_RaceTimes<- pred_SVM
View(SVMTest) #Returns 13214 rows
View(pred_SVM) #Returns 12830
```

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Pred_RaceTime, value = c(`2` = 27.1766438249356,  : 
  replacement has 12830 rows, data has 13214

Comment: I cannot really help you with svm, but usually data are dropped when there is a missing value for one of the covariates.
Also, I would recommend to use the tag `r` instead of `rstudio` as it is a R questions not related to Rstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the command, you need to get rid of the `NA` values in your dataset. SVM is handling it for you so that, the `pred_SVM` output is calculated **without** the NA values.

To test if there exist `NA` in your data, just run :  `sum(is.na(SVMTest))`

I am pretty sure that you will see a number greater than zero.

Before starting to build your SVM algorithm, get rid of all `NA` values by,

```
dataset <- dataset[complete.cases(dataset), ]
```

Then after separating your data into Train and Test sets you can run ,

```
SVM_swim <- svm(.....,data = SVMTrain, kernel='linear')
```